# MySQL regex woes

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

MySQL has decided not to play ball with a certain regular expression I put together. The grand plan is for it to match a string which might or might not be terminated by a punctuation mark.

I have entered the following into 2 apps designed to validate regular expressions, and in both cases the expression works flawlessly:

```
\bString\b[[:punct:]]?
```

But the moment this is introduced to MySQL as

```
[[:<:]]String[[:>:]][[:punct:]]?
```

Then it doesn't work at all. It will accept *String* **but not** *String!* or *String;*

I am at wit's end, so if anyone could shed some light on this, I would be deeply grateful!

TIA :-)

Comment: 2 things: What version of mysql? Also, the mysql manual warns about using regexp on multi-byte character sets so you should check that this isn't causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[:>:]]` means end of word. Usually a space.

`String` (note the spaces) matches.
`String!`  does not match.

Change the regex into:

```
[[:<:]]String[[:>:]]{0,1}[[:punct:]]{0,1}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Johan! It worked a treat :-) I think I have a fair idea why the addition of those bounds ({0,1}) works, but would you mind explaining exactly how the use of bounds suddenly causes the expression to match the punctuation?

Comment: The bounds `{0,1}` means zero or one (spaces and/or punctuation marks).

Comment: Thanks! The only problem that has now arisen is that the expression isn't respecting the word boundaries. So if I want to find the word _car_, for example, it will end up matching _carrier_, _carrot_, _carnage_, &c. Any ideas?